# QTableView: change rowCount on the fly

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I use a `QTableView` to show read-only data. The model is based upon a `QList` of a custom type that contains another `QList`. Something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int range;
    QString description;
} Field;

typedef struct
{
    QString name;
    QList<Field> fields;
} Item;

QList<Item> items;
```

In my `QAbstractTableModel` implementation I have a slot that selects the current `item`:

```
void setCurrentItem(int idx)
{
    // checks for errors (omissis)
    currentItemIdx = idx;

    // ask to redraw the table
    emit dataChanged(this->index(0, 0), this->index(rowCount(), columnCount()));
}
```

All the model's logic rely on that item, for example:

```
int MyModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex&) const {
    return items.at(m_currentItemIdx).fields.count();
}

QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    if (!index.isValid()) return QVariant();
    if (index.row() >= items.at(m_currentItemIdx).fields.count()) return QVariant();

    Field f = items.at(m_currentItemIdx).fields.at(index.row);
    switch (role) {
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
        switch (index.column()){
        case 0:
            return f.range;
            break;

        case 1:
            return f.description;
            break;

        default:
            return QVariant();
        }
        break;
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

The problem is when I change the current item using `setCurrentItem()` the code uses the new data, but the `QTableView` doesn't change its rows and then doesn't request the new content.

I thought `emit dataChanged()` was enought but it seems it doesn't.
What should I do to notify the view that I've changed the size of my model?

I'm trying to avoid the insert/remove row mechanism because I don't want to change the actual data in the `QList`, I just want to pick up a different set of information.

Comment: Since you completely update your table's data, I think, calling `QAbstractItemModel::reset()` will perform what you want. I.e. `void setCurrentItem(int idx) { currentItemIdx = idx; reset(); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the `QAbstractItemModel::​beginResetModel()` before and the `QAbstractItemModel::​endResetModel()` after changing your model data.

Like this:

```
void setCurrentItem(int idx)
{
  beginResetModel();
  currentItemIdx = idx;
  endResetModel();
}
```